# render_to_string in lib class not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templating

I'm trying to use `delayed_job` to update a remote database via xml

In my lib folder I put a file with a class that should do a `render_to_text` with `template.xml.builder`, but I get:

```
undefined method `render_to_string' for #<SyncJob:0x7faf4e6c0480>...
```

*What am I doing wrong?*

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
ac = ActionController::Base.new()
ac.render_to_string(:partial => '/path/to/your/template', :locals => {:varable => somevarable})
```

Comment: If you are trying to use it with instance variable, go like this `:locals => {:@instance_variable => value}`

Comment: I am getting Missing template error, it seems like it doesn't found that partial and I have checked many times for spelling. still nothing.. Please help

Comment: You'll get "Missing template" error because `ActionController::Base` will search within `action_controller/base` path. Delegate to another controller. It usually inherits `ActionController::Base` anyway.

Comment: Also, if you want to use it with a regular page (not a partial), just leave out the `:partial =>` part, like this: `ac.render_to_string('/path/to/your/template', :locals => {:varable => somevarable})` (note the path is from inside the /views directory, e.g. you could have `'users/index.html.erb'`)

Answer (score 8):

I had problems with a undefined helper method then I used `ApplicationController`

```
ApplicationController.new.render_to_string
```

Comment: Same here. Did you ever fix the undefined helper?

Comment: In my case i forgot a namespace when calling AplicationController.

I try: 

`Usr::ApplicationController.new.render_to_string`

And it works.

Answer (score 3):

`render_to_string` is defined in `ActionController::Base`. Since the class/module is defined outside the scope of the Rails controllers the function is not available.

You are going to have to manually render the file. I don't know what you are using for your templates (ERB, Haml, etc.). But you are going to have load the template and parse it yourself.

So if ERB, something like this:

```
require 'erb'

x = 42
template = ERB.new <<-EOF
  The value of x is: <%= x %>
EOF
puts template.result(binding)
```

You will have to open the template file and send the contents to `ERB.new`, but that an exercise left for you. Here are the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/) for ERB.

That's the general idea.

Answer (score 3):

## Rails 5

`render_to_string` and others are now available as class methods on the controller. So you may do the following with whatever controller you prefer: `ApplicationController.render_to_string`

I specifically needed to assign a dynamic instance variable for the templates based on an object's class so my example looked like:

```
ApplicationController.render_to_string(
  assigns: { :"#{lowercase_class}" => document_object },
  inline: '' # or whatever templates you want to use
)
```

Great blog post by the developer who made the rails PR: https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/new-feature-in-rails-5-render-views-outside-of-actions

Answer (score 2):

You could turn your `template.xml.builder` into a partial (`_template.xml.builder`) and then render it by instantiating an `ActionView::Base` and calling `render`

```
av = ActionView::Base.new(Rails::Configuration.new.view_path)
av.extend ApplicationController.master_helper_module
xml = av.render :partial => 'something/template'
```

I haven't tried it with xml yet, but it works well with html partials.

Comment: I get: undefined method `new' for Rails::Configuration:Module